# what is "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr' " after I use shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

The class `Request`  adds itself into a class `EventLoop`. The shared_ptr `loop` is not nullptr. However, I get some problems.
The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Request;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Request> RequestPtr;


class EventLoop
{
public:
    EventLoop();
    ~EventLoop();
    vector<RequestPtr> relist;

    void add_request(RequestPtr re)
    {
        relist.push_back(re);
    }
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<EventLoop> EventLoopPtr;

EventLoop::EventLoop() {}
EventLoop::~EventLoop() {}


class Request: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Request>
{
public:
    Request();
    ~Request();
    EventLoopPtr loop;

    void add_inself()
    {
        loop->add_request(shared_from_this());
        cout << "Yes, success adding into it" << endl;
    }
};

Request::Request(): loop(std::make_shared<EventLoop>())
{}

Request::~Request() 
{}

int main()
{
    Request r;
    r.add_inself();

    std::cout << "END" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error message is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
what():  bad_weak_ptr
Aborted
```

Any solutions? **Thank you very much**

Comment: I use C pointer instead of shared_ptr, it is ok.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please try to avoid constructor and destructors that doesn't do anything. If you feel the need to explicitly declare them then mark them as `default` (as in `EventLoop() = default;`), but even that should not be needed here.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the `shared_from_this`, you need to have that shared pointer. In `main` function, try instantiating not a heap object `Request`, but `std::shared_ptr<Request> r = std::make_shared<Request>(); r->add_inself();`

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot.It is very kind of you.